# Get the finance stocks key development links from Reuters

Tags: android, yql, stocks, yahoo-finance, reuters

I am developing an android application which gives stock information using YQL. In the Yahoo interactive charts there are **key developments** as shown in the link:  http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=MSFT+Interactive#symbol=msft;range=1y;compare=;indicator=ke_sd+volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined;

Yahoo accesses the key developments information from Reuters. Link: http://in.reuters.com/finance/stocks/MSFT.OQ/key-developments

It would be really helpful if anyone would point me out how I can get the **key developments** from Reuters in android using web services or rss feeds or any other possible way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [file that the webpage requests upon loading the chart](http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/msft/chartdata;type=quote;ys=2005;yz=4;ts=1234567890/csv). What's even better, is that if you swap the `/csv` part in the url for `/json`, [you get a file with some shiny JSON](http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/msft/chartdata;type=quote;ys=2005;yz=4;ts=1234567890/json) instead, more suitable for Android use.

Comment: Thank you ninetwozero for your reply. I already have the data, all I need is the key developments (with date) you can see in the chart (labelled as "K").

Comment: Ouf, unfortunately I think they're providing it inline with the HTML upon requesting the page. :(

Comment: so is there absolutely no way that i could access it?? :(

Comment: That'd be by scraping with a HTML/DOM-parser. :)

Comment: what does `ys`, `yz` and `ts` refer to in the query `http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/msft/chartdata;type=quote;ys=2005;yz=4;ts=1234567890/json`?

Comment: My guess is the following: ``ys``=``year``, ``ts``=``timestamp`` but I don't really know what ``yz`` might be.

Comment: ys: Starting Year?, yz: Total Years from the Specified Starting Year?